# OpenCover report

Tags: .net, testing, code-coverage, opencover

We are using OpenCover to examine our code coverage. We have big number of test and as a result OpenCover generates ~100 reports. ReportGenerator creates summary of Sequence Coverage, but we also need to know branch coverage summary of all tests, so it is possible to count Branch Coverage in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pre-release of OpenCover](http://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCover/4.5.3311-rc24) allows you to accumulate the results of one coverage run into the next.

Use `-mergeoutput -results:coverage.xml` to load a previous `coverage.xml` and save as an updated version.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatize this with powershell script:
https://github.com/rpokrovskij/opencover4vs.ps1/blob/master/opencover4vs.ps1

Just configure two parameters (which dlls to include and which namespaces to include):

```
$TestDllsPatterns = @(,'*\bin\Debug\Vse.*.Test.dll')  
$TestableCodeNamespacePatterns = @(,'*')
```